# How do you disable the addition of / at the end of a single tag in Prettier in VS Code in HTML?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

How do you disable the addition of / at the end of a single tag in Prettier in VS Code in HTML?

How do you disable the addition of / at the end of a single tag in Pr ettier in VS Code in HTML
How do you disable the addition of / at the end of a single tag in Pr ettier in VS Code in HTM

Comment: You did not need to write the same line 3 times. And can you be more clear with what are you saying?

Comment: It required the question to be more than 290 characters, so I inserted it 3 times. My question is completely understandable. I want to disable the addition of "/" at the end of a single HTML tag in visual-studio-code when pharmacing HTML code via Prettier

Comment: Whatever question I ask, they write "not clear". Although it is absolutely clear, and there is nothing more to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on Visual Studio 2019, you go to the settings, and you search for "HTML", under Text "Editor -> HTML -> Advanced" you have to search for the 'Automaticcaly insert closure tags' toggle.
Visual Studio is pretty similar to Visual Studio Code, so you should be able to untick that toggle too.